# Virtual join-directory on Windows

Tags: compact-disc, optical-drive, hardlink

Problem:
Say I have a video spanned over 2 files (vid001.avi & vid002.avi) and each file is on a seperate CD/DVD. If the 2 files are in the same directory my player will automatically play the second file after the first, but since the files are on different CD's this will not work.

I would like to join these CD's to one (virtual) directory so that my player starts playing the second file after the first, but without copying te files.

I already tried things with hardlinks (softlinks won't work, as far as I know), but there seem to be too many restrictions.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't explicitly mention it, so I have to ask: are using two cd/dvd drives?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a player, like VLC, that supports "playlists", then you could just have it play those files from where ever you put them?